# Snakemake how to ignore a RuntimeWarning?

Tags: python, snakemake

Unlike the default Python behaviour, Snakemake is stopping execution upon a RuntimeWarnings thrown by numpy.

```
/a-path/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3250: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN slice encountered
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Configuring numpy.seterr using the code below does not help.

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='print')
```

How can I simply tell snakemake not to terminate the rule for warnings?

Note: I am using the `run:` option in snakemake for the rule that is throwing the `RuntimeWarning`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have an actual error somewhere else. On 5.4.2, the warnings seem ok:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'foo.txt',

rule one:
    output:
        touch('foo.txt'),
    run:
        import numpy as np
        np.nanmax([np.nan, np.nan])
```

Execution:

snakemake

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   all
    1   one
    2

[Tue Jun 11 21:09:47 2019]
rule one:
    output: foo.txt
    jobid: 1

Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   one
    1
/home/dario/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py:19: RuntimeWarning: All-NaN axis encountered
  from snakemake.logging import logger, format_resources, format_resource_names
Touching output file foo.txt.
[Tue Jun 11 21:09:47 2019]
Finished job 1.
1 of 2 steps (50%) done

[Tue Jun 11 21:09:47 2019]
localrule all:
    input: foo.txt
    jobid: 0

[Tue Jun 11 21:09:47 2019]
Finished job 0.
2 of 2 steps (100%) done
Complete log: /home/dario/Tritume/.snakemake/log/2019-06-11T210947.007675.snakemake.log
```

In any case, you can silence errors with

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: In your case the warning is already at the end of the program. What happens if you have some more python code to produce output that takes longer than the `latency-wait`?

Comment: You are right, the error is probably somewhere else. Though I cannot reproduce it now.